# Scikit learn - High accuracy on the testing set

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a data set containing 100000 rows and 129 columns. I use `pandas` to load it into a data frame and split the set into 2 subset: training (70%) of the parent set and testing (30%). This is the code I used for splitting

```
def makeSample(df):
  test_size = len(df.index) * 30 / 100
  rows = random.sample(df.index, test_size)

  testing = df.ix[rows]
  training = df.drop(rows)

  print "Number of testing set %s\n" % len(testing.index)
  print "Number of training set %s\n" % len(training.index)

  return training, testing

def split9Folds(df):
  for x in xrange(1, 10):
    training, testing = makeSample(df)

    training.to_csv(r'split/training_%s.csv' % x, header=None, index=None, sep=',', mode='w')
    testing.to_csv(r'split/testing_%s.csv' % x, header=None, index=None, sep=',', mode='w')
```

The splitting process will be taken in 9 folds. Overall, I have 9 pairs of training/testing file. I then use decision tree from `Scikit-learn` to train

```
df_file = "split/training_9.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(df_file, sep=',', header=None)
df.columns = xrange(1, len(df.columns) + 1)

## remove the id column 
df.drop(df.columns[[4]], axis=1, inplace=True)

## remove the class column
features_column = list(df.columns[1:])
target_column = list(df.columns[0:1])

tr_features_list = df[features_column]
tr_target_list = df[target_column]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=20, random_state=99)
clf = clf.fit(tr_features_list, tr_target_list)
```

And then use the testing file in order to test the accuracy. What surprise me is when testing the accuracy score is always 1 (100% accuracy)

```
t_file = "split/testing_9.csv"
t_df = pd.read_csv(t_file, sep=',', header=None)
t_df.columns = xrange(1, len(t_df.columns) + 1)
t_df.drop(t_df.columns[[4]], axis=1, inplace=True)

t_features_list = t_df[features_column]
t_target_list = t_df[target_column]

score = clf.score(t_features_list, t_target_list)

print score
```

Look like I am having overfitting problem or other problem during the training process. This happens to all the testing sets as well. Can you give me some suggestions for this?

Comment: Not sure about the reason you get a 100% accuracy, but one enhancement may be to use pandas named fields instead of using `df.columns`. It makes things clearer and is less error prone than integer based indexing.

Comment: @ldirer : yes, i agreed. The problem is the data set does not come with any named column (KDD cup 2008 data set). Thus, I just let it there

Comment: Ok. I'd still use the integer index rather than the columns attribute. By default when you load your dataframe you get integer names for fields.  
Specifically this part looks weird to me:
`t_df.columns = xrange(1, len(t_df.columns) + 1)`. 
When you use `drop` on the next line, the field you are dropping is based on the index and not on your df.columns attribute. Not sure that's what you intended.

Comment: @ldirer: you are right. I misunderstand the drop function. It is using the column index, not the column name. I thought when I re-define the columns, then it will go with the column name, not the index. The reason I re-define the column is I want to translate the requirement easier to the code

Comment: You can pass column names when loading the dataframe if you'd rather have fields from 1 to n + 1 than from 0 to n.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have confused concepts of DecisionTree (single decision tree) and some ensemble meta-estimator (many classifiers such as DecisionTree).
I dont see anything wrong in your results. Without any restrictions decision tree can **always** separate your dataset perfectly. Because it can approximate any decision boundary. That's what happening in your case. The only restriction on DecisonTree that you have - `min_samples_split=20`. But 20 is almost nothing comparing to your dataset size (100k samples).

If you want to build more restricted (generalized) tree - you can play with max_depth, min_samples_split (increase it),  min_samples_leaf, [etc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier).